# how to pass default URL into default browser in IOS?

Tags: ios

I have pass this below code in `viewDidLoad` method but it take the https:// not the the passed URL so i am confused please tell me the solution of my problem if anybody can know.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *customURL = @"http://www.dannoshottips.com/";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not required for add  `https://` in url because your site is not use `https://` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Your site www.dannoshottips.com not https protocol used.

this site not secure protocol used so you can not use `https://`.

[http://www.dannoshottips.com/](https://www.dannoshottips.com/)

[1](https://www.dannoshottips.com/): http://www.dannoshottips.com/ is open in browser

https://www.dannoshottips.com/ is not open in browser.